# Finding curve knowing unit tangent vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Assume we have a curve $C$ parametrized by arc lenght by $\vec r(s)$ and we have the unit tangent vector $\vec{T}(s)=\langle a(s), b(s)\rangle$ and normal tangent vector $\vec{N}(s)=\langle c(s), d(s)\rangle$.

So i have the two following problems

1. I want to solve the following system with inital data $a(0)=0,b(0)=1$.

\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\frac{d a}{d s}=-K \cdot b(s) \\
\frac{d b}{d s}=K \cdot a(s)
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

2. And want to find $\vec r(s)$ such that
   \begin{equation}
   \frac{d \vec{r}}{d s}=\vec{T}(s), \quad \vec{r}(0)=\left\langle\frac{1}{K}, 0\right\rangle
   \end{equation}

I would like to know if i can solve explicitly these two problems, because no matter what direction I see these problems, I cannot find a solution where i can evaluate in the initial conditions.

What I've tried is to solve the differential equations just integrating in both sides but this is not getting me anywhere.

Any help would be appreciated, and thank you in advance.

Comment: In the first (I assume $K$ is constant, is it right?), take $\frac{da}{ds}=-Kb$ and differentiate by $s$ again to obtain $\frac{d^2a}{ds^2}=-K\frac{db}{ds}=-K^2a$ and same for $b$ you get $\frac{d^2b}{ds^2}=-K^2b$. Can you think of solutions $a,b$ for the previous two second order differential equations?

Comment: Oh, that was the trick, i couldn't see it, just with that I can solve the whole problem.  Thank you.